# GStreamer # symbol in uri of local file

Tags: python, gstreamer, pygst

When I try to play local file with "#" in filename on my Linux machine, it displays:

```
Error: message about my installation of GStreamer missing plugin /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/gst-plugins-base-0.10.36-r1/work/gst-plugins-base-0.10.36/gst/playback/gstplaybasebin.c(1686): gen_source_element (): /GstPlayBin:player:
No URI handler for file
```

I use this to set URI:

```
self.player.set_property('uri', 'file://' + filepath)
```

where filepath is absolute path to e.g. MP3 file "/home/me/untitled #1.mp3"

Is there some kind of escape or workaround?

Comment: No one replied so I managed to rename files.

Answer (score 0):

`filepath` should be URL quoted.

Use `urllib.parse.quote()` (Python 3) or `urllib.quote()` (Python 2)

This is what I use (Python 3) which should work on Windows too:

```
def file_to_uri(filename):
    filepath = os.path.abspath(filename) 
    drive, filepath = os.path.splitdrive(filepath)
    filepath = urllib.parse.quote(filepath.replace(os.sep, '/'))
    return 'file://%s%s' % (drive, filepath)
```

Comment: `urllib.parse.quote()` don't work, do `from urllib import parse` and then simply `parse.quote()`